# Use properties in a schema to calculate value of a property for that particular schema in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have deinfed a schema for payments. In that I have two properties - `invoiceAmount` and `amountPaid`. I need to store another field called `balance` in the same schema.

```
balance = invoiceAmount - amountPaid
```

**payment.js**

```
const PaymentSchema = new Schema({
    ...

    invoiceAmount: {type: Number, required: true},
    amountPaid: {type: Number, required: true},
    balance: {
        type: Number, value: () => {
            return this.invoiceAmount - this.amountPaid //Logic that should look like this
        },
        required: true
    },

    ...
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

How to implement the above logic when creating a new Payment Object ? It always shows me the issue :

```
balance: ValidatorError: Path `balance` is required.
```

Please keep in mind that if the `amountPaid` or `invoiceAmount` is changed then even the `balance` property should be updated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this could be a solution:
**payment.js**

```
const paymentSchema = new Schema({
      invoiceAmount: {
          type: Number,
          required: true
      },
      amountPaid: {
          type: Number,
          required: true
      }
      balance: {
         type: Number,
         required: true
      }
});
```

Then, to implement the logic that you're talking about, call `findByIdAndUpdate()` in a `patch` route and `$set` the balance the way you wrote: `invoiceAmount - amountPaid`. You can do a request to this route every time you need to update the `balance`. Something like:

```
app.patch('/updateBalance', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
    const balance = await Payment.findByIdAndUpdate({ $set: { balance: invoiceAmount - amountPaid }});
    console.log(balance);
    res.status(200).json({ balance });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error });
      }
}
```

Of course you have to adapt my solution to your logic.